# run windows command from bash with output to standard out?

Tags: windows, powershell, cygwin, mingw, cmd

Folks, I'm using git tools such as git bisect run which need to call a command to build and test my project. My command to do is nant which is a windows program.  Or a build.cmd script which calls nant.

It's easy to get the bash to call the nant build to run.

But the hard part is how to get the standard output written to a file?

I even installed the Windows PowerShell to try running a command from bash.

Again, it works but the standard output fill says "permission denied" when
I try to read it while the build is going on.

Update:

When running nant, the entire path is used. It is installed and runs fine. The problem is how to get the standard output when running from bash.

If running nant from the windows prompt with "> build.out" at the end of the line, you will get the standard out. But the same never works under bash. It just says build.out is locked, permissions denied.

Update:

Using tee as suggested below also doesn't solve the problem. In that case the file still report "access is denied" with any attempts to read it while the build runs. But also, the tee program never writes anything to standard output.

Comment: erm... bash is a unix(esc) shell... unless you have install 'nant' into windows you can run its command. You will also need to either register nant so you can call it from anywhere, or move to the directory where it is, then call the command.

Comment: Thanks, I made an update to answer your questions.  Nant is installed and we use the fully qualified path for nant. The problem is related to how to get standard output to a file and tail -f on the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally resolved this. It turns out the the nant build script was using git feature to erase all ignored files to cleanup. That was deleting the build.out file can causing these strange issues. Now, the process writes the build.out file to a parent directory so that it won't get deleted and now everything works smoothly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

(If I am understanding your question correctly...)

You can probably use the 'tee' command to split the output to both a file and stdout. The line `echo I am building something | tee build.out` will both print the output on the console and save it to the file named "build.out".

The tee command is usually available in Cygwin, and also apparently in the Bash shell installed by msysgit (where I just tested it). Here's a [good reference page](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/tee.shtml) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Using tee as described has the same problem and an additional one. That is the file stills give the "access is denied" errors if you try to open it with any editor or tail, less, head, cat, etc. Also, strangely, the tee program doesn't write anything to the stdandard out. It's silent. But the file size is growing. Just simply still impossible to "monitor" what's going on.